# Video is too much buffering

Tags: video, streaming, mp4, buffering

I am developing a website like Udemy using Laravel, where user purchase course and watch a course with different topics. but i am facing an issue when any user watch course any topic video the video is to much buffering, can someone help me? how can i fast buffering of videos. I am using HTML5 video tag and mp4 video.

Comment: Please understand that we can't help to fix an invisible problem. Try to make a demo page with one video so we see the problem in action and advise you. **(1)** The problem could be anything from a slow server, or too large a resolution of video, or the Laravel code is messing things up for you. Does Laravel send data in pieces and directly to the HTML5 player? **(2)** Does the _"Too much buffering"_ part happen before or during playback? If before playback, then it's possible that your code is downloading the whole video first (eg: 500mb), and only after that part is when playback now begins.